# How to logout users after they have liked a page with the Facebook Like plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a very small webpage to use in a kiosk stand. The goal is to let people "Like" a facebook page on location with a touchscreen.

Users have to login first to like a page, so Facebook will come up with their regular Login popup, which works like a charm. When the user logged in, the page is liked (since they clicked the "Like"-button) and the user should be logged out again (since no-one wants to be logged in on a public computer). The page should reload after that.

Now this is possible with the Javascript API from Facebook. They have an event listener that calls a function when a user likes a page. I just have to call FB.logout() when that event triggers :) .

Unfortunatly, it isn't working for me. I could be very dumb, or the Facebook API is bugged.

My code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work, and I think the problem lies in the Login part from Facebook.

Does anyone has any experience with this? It should be very simple, but I can't get it to work...

Some things I have tried:

- Prompt a normal login - Possible, but it says that my app needs access to some information. Really the only thing I want to do is get users to like a page.
- setTimeout loop - Tried this, but the Facebook Login seems to stop Javascript as a whole on my page?

EDIT: I know that it is a bad idea for people to insert their credentials into a public computer, but the customer wants it this way. There is also a QR-code which links to the Facebook page, but that doesn't solve my problem :) .

**TL;DR: Facebook Javascript callback from the "Like"-button works when a user is Logged in, but fails when a user has to log-in via the Facebook pop-up.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunatly, it isn't working for me. I could be very dumb, or the Facebook API is bugged.

Nope. The problem lies in your approach, resp. the concept.

FB.logout *only* works with an active access token (since otherwise, *any* site I visit on the net could log me out of Facebook, and that would be hugely annoying).

But since the user does not connect to your app, you don’t have an access token.

> Prompt a normal login - Possible, but it says that my app needs access to some information.

That is the *only* way you will get an access token, and since the only way you can use FB.logout.

(And if the user logs in to Facebook, but then denies connecting to your app, again you will not have an access token, so you can’t log them out in that case either.)

Comment: I was indeed thinking the same thing, and I think I got fooled by my own application / Facebook account. Since I am the owned of the app, I naturally give access to the app, and logging out works. Logging out would have failed with any other user. I really need a developer account for Facebook... Thanks!